# synaptic seems to have only already installed packages

Tags: package-management, synaptic, source-packages

My synaptic seems to have only already installed packages:

Here what I see

[image]

I have tried to reload the source list as:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.save /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I have also tried to go to software and update to reload all:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

or to up-date

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398923/edit) and add more details. The Synaptic is a package manager. This app will always show all the installed packages. The Ubuntu OS is made of packages. So, as soon as you install Ubuntu there will be packages in Synaptic.

Comment: if you click "Reload" (above left), does it stay the same? Or click "Status" (on the left, now "Sections" is active) and Reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sorted by Installed

You may have inadvertently sorted the list of apps by installation **S**tatus.

[image]

Click on the **S** above the the green boxes twice to go back to the default sort order.

## Sorted by Package

You may also click on **Package** column header to sort by package name.

[image]

Hope this helps